# please solve here retain count of NSString objects in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, copy, retaincount

Please solve this.

```
NSString *S1 = @"abc";
//retain count of s1 ??

NSString *S2 = [S1 copy];
//retain count of s2 and s1 ??

NSString *S3 = [S2 copy];
//retain count of s3 and s2 ??

NSString *S4 = [S3 retain];
//retain count of s4 and s3 ??

NSString *S1 = @"xyz";
//retain count of s1, s2, s3 and s4 ??
```

Do not suggest `retainCount` because i believe that does not give exact result.

Comment: This smells like homework. What do you think the answers are?

Comment: `retainCount` returns a perfectly exact result. It just may not be what you expect.

Comment: `NSLog(@"\nretain count=%d",[obj retainCount]);` returns all the way `-1`..!!

Comment: `retainCount` returns an unsigned value, an `NSUInteger`. You should use `%u` in your format string.

Comment: I tried that also. That returns `4294967295` everywhere.

Comment: Exactly.  Retain Count is unreliable, unpredictable, and above all ***completely worthless***.  Do not ship it in production code.

Comment: [Your objects are constant strings and will never get deallocated.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1390334/nsstring-retain-count) It doesn't matter how many times you call `copy` or `retain`, it won't affect the memory management of the object at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Edited thanks to clarification from @KurtRevis*

Assuming ARC is off, of course, you could test this yourself.  But you may not understand why you are getting these results.  Here is what you should be getting and why.

```
NSString *S1 = @"abc";
//retain count of s1 ??
```

`S1` is a constant string literal that will never go leave memory as long as your app is running. So retain count is sort of irrelevant.

```
NSString *S2 = [S1 copy];
//retain count of s2 and s1 ??
```

`S1` is unchanged.  `S2` is a copy of `S1` with retain count of 1, *with no autorelease*.

```
NSString *S3 = [S2 copy];
//retain count of s3 and s2 ??
```

`S2` is unchanged at 1 *with no autorelease*.  `S3` is a copy of `S2` with retain count of 1, *with no autorelease*.

```
NSString *S4 = [S3 retain];
//retain count of s4 and s3 ??
```

`S4` and `S3` now point *to the same object*. And that one object now has a retain count of 2, with an autorelease. Once autorelease is triggered, it will have a retain count of 1, and will not be deallocated.

```
NSString *S1 = @"xyz";
//retain count of s1, s2, s3 and s4 ??
```

The old object `S1` used to point to is unchanged, it's a persistant string in memory.  And now `S1` points to a new string which is treated the same way as what `S1` used to point to.

---

Or just save yourself some headaches and use ARC :)

Comment: Thanx Alex. Its a part of an Interview and interviewer always tries to capture interviewee's `memory management` concepts by going beyond ARC. Offcource I can not put `retain` if i am using ARC.

Comment: There is no autoreleasing happening here. Referring to a constant string doesn't autorelease anything. There would be no point -- it's a constant string, it will never go away, and there is nothing to "clean up". Try setting a breakpoint on `-[NSObject autorelease]` and run the code -- the breakpoint will not be hit.

Comment: @KurtRevis Yeah I suppose. For me it's been easiest to treat them like an autoreleased instance, since you handle the object in the same fashion. But I think you are right that that's not quite correct.

Comment: @AlexWayne : All these most of us know, but kindly let us know when we print the `retainCount` why it doesn't reflect the same?

Comment: `retainCount` might be working in previous iOS versions because I found this post of 2009: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407517/can-you-send-retain-counts-to-nslog-to-aid-learning and this post of 2008: http://www.roseindia.net/iphone/objectivec/memory-management.shtml

Comment: The absolute retain count is useless.  It won't be 1, either, because of an implementation detail.  Nor will any copies of the string be made.  If an interviewer asked this same question and thought the above was correct, the interviewer doesn't know what they are talking about.

Answer (score 9):

> Do not suggest retainCount because i believe that does not give exact
>   result.

Correct.  `retainCount` is useless.  www.whentouseretaincount.com

You can only usefully reason about retain counts as deltas.

---

To answer your question, for that code, the retain count is a constant and none of the lines of code actually do much of anything.   At the end of that code, S2, S3 and S4 will all have the same value;  will all point to the same string (and, obviously, S1 will point to a different string).

This is because of an implementation detail.   You are working with a constant string.  It is, effectively, a singleton.  Thus, there is never a need to copy the string (`copy` just does `return self;`) and the retain/release/autorelease methods do absolutely nothing.